# No route matches "/status" rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, middleware, puma

I am having rails 5 application with puma appserver and nginx webserver. Recently I am seeing my puma logs I am seeing below error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/status"):
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57]   
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/load_interlock.rb:13:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] newrelic_rpm (4.5.0.337) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57] puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57]   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57]   Rendered collection of /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [404 times] (290.6ms)
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57]   Rendered collection of /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [6 times] (4.4ms)
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57]   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (17.9ms)
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57]   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (22.0ms)
[b09723a1-d68b-4148-ab12-8ff2e7d4cb57]   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (439.5ms)
[3ba2adfb-2f26-4a97-8e7c-f424d759a398] Started GET "/server-status?auto" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-11 07:22:47 +0000
```

Even though there is no traffic to the app I am seeing app is running and consuming memory.

When I see my newrelic reports most time consuming requests the first request is: `Middleware/Rack/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call` causing my server down after few mins due to memory overflow. I am not getting any clue to identify the issue and resolve. I am struggling with this from past 2 days but no clue.

Could you please help me to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as i understand, its in production? where ist hosted?

Comment: @7urkm3n Yes it is production.  We are using AWS